# Conditional Examination of Dates within a Matrix Field

Tags: matrix, conditionals, date

We are utilizing a Matrix field to list information by date (each day has it's own row - first column being "date".  We want only today's row to be displayed (similar to a calendar).  HOWEVER, if an entry containing matrix rows - all of which are outdated, then a note to display "outdated" should appear.

Channel Entry : Department
Channel Field : Calendar (Matrix)
Columns:  Date | Information

For entries that contain an updated monthly calendar, we are correctly identifying and displaying the single row with today's information using this code:

```
{calendar}
    {if "{date format='%Y%m%d'}" == "{current_time format='%Y%m%d'}"}
        <information here>
    {if}
{/calendar}
```

BUT, we need it to be a conditional examination of the all of the matrix rows within the entry so that if none of the rows matches current_time, then a notice of "outdated calendar" displays.

Here's the catch - when we have used conditionals like the following, we get repeated display of "outdated" for every row that does not match today.

```
{calendar}
    {if "{date format='%Y%m%d'}" == "{current_time format='%Y%m%d'}"}
        <information here>
    {if:elseif "{date format='%Y%m%d'}" != "{current_time format='%Y%m%d'}"}
        <"Your calendar is outdated">
    {/if}
{/calendar}
```

Thus this results in 30 rows of "Your calendar is outdated" - instead of just one.

We ONLY want one item displayed - either today's info (on a row that contains today's date) - OR outdated (if no rows match today's date)

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can search to see if there are any rows which have a current or future date, then proceed accordingly:

```
{if '{calendar:total_rows search:date=">={current_time}"}' > 0}
    Your calendar is outdated
{if:else}
    {calendar}
        {if "{date format='%Y%m%d'}" == "{current_time format='%Y%m%d'}"}
            <information here>
        {if}
    {/calendar}
{/if}
```